# msgpack unserialising dict key strings to bytes

Tags: python, msgpack

I am having issues with `msgpack` in python. It seems that when serialising a `dict`, if the keys are strings `str`, they are not unserialised properly and causing `KeyError` exceptions to be raised.

Example:

```
>>> import msgpack
>>> d = dict()
>>> value = 1234
>>> d['key'] = value
>>> binary = msgpack.dumps(d)
>>> new_d = msgpack.loads(binary)
>>> new_d['key']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'key'
```

This is because the keys are not strings after calling `loads()` but are unserialised to `bytes` objects.

```
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys(['key'])
>>> new_d.keys()
dict_keys([b'key'])
```

It seems this is related to a unimplemented feature as mentioned [in github](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/issues/121)

My question is, Is there a way to fix this issue or a work around to ensure that the same keys can be used upon deserialisation?

I would like to use `msgpack` but if I cannot build a `dict` object with `str` keys and expect to be able to use the same key upon deserilisation, it becomes useless.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/issues/121#issuecomment-13815058 I suggest that you encode _all_ strings to UTF-8 before passing them to msgpack and then decode upon unpacking. Doing that will also prevent Unicode outside the ASCII / Latin1 range from getting mangled.

Comment: thanks! this was the issue but the source is related to encoding problems with `msgpack`. you helped track down the problem. answer to follow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A default encoding is set when calling `dumps` or `packb`

```
:param str encoding:
 |      Convert unicode to bytes with this encoding. (default: 'utf-8')
```

but it is *not* set by default when calling `loads` or `unpackb` as seen in:

```
Help on built-in function unpackb in module msgpack._unpacker:

unpackb(...)
    unpackb(... encoding=None, ... )
```

Therefore changing the encoding on the deserialisation fixes the issue, for example:

```
>>> d['key'] = 1234
>>> binary = msgpack.dumps(d)
>>> msgpack.loads(binary, encoding = "utf-8")
{'key': 1234}
>>> msgpack.loads(binary, encoding = "utf-8") == d
True
```

Comment: encoding is deprecated -- raw=True|False is the new method.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `raw=False` flag as such worked for me on your example:

```py
msgpack.unpackb(binary, raw=False)
# or
msgpack.loads(binary, raw=False)
```

See https://msgpack-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#msgpack.Unpacker:

> raw (bool) – If true, unpack msgpack raw to Python bytes. Otherwise, unpack to Python str by decoding with UTF-8 encoding (default).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def c_msgpackloads(bin):
    new_d = msgpack.loads(bin)
    new_d = {key.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(key, bytes) else key: new_d[key].decode('utf-8') if isinstance(new_d[key], bytes) else new_d[key] for key in new_d}
    return new_d
```

It's a custom loading function that loads the dict and automatically encodes  `bytes` keys and values to utf-8 strings.

Comment: thanks, pedro. nice hack but it is just an encoding issue. will post answer.